# Problems with text boxes after saving file in inkscape

Tags: inkscape, svg, save, text-on-path, bounding-box

After saving my logo in inkscape, I'm facing a problem with the text's boxes and alignments. The problem is that when I'm going to open it on krita as svg, the textbox is way bigger than the one I created, and the other one is not in the center as suppose. I will send some images to help.

In Inkscape:

[image: In Inkscape]

In Krita:

[image: In Krita]

PS: Already tried to convert both to text (Text > Convert To Text), and save in PLAIN.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. It's difficult to answer this without access to the SVG. Did you scale the text down using a transform? If so, perhaps try setting the point size, without using any scaling to achieve the desired size.  Or  alternatively change the preferences for storing transforms: in *Edit > Preferences > Behaviour > Transforms,* under Store Transformation, select "Optimized" to prevent Inkscape from using a Transform in the SVG when you scale anything.

Comment: Hello, I didn't scaled it manually, I just typed and add the correct letter size. in sequence, aligned. My inkscape is already in that mode. I'll send the svg file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lb12yo4GcJOvCG64fo9RaAY9zXEKE5Ym/view?usp=sharing

PS: Now, aparrently, when you open to see in Drive, the text dissapear, but normaly works on inkscape...

Comment: Try converting the text to paths in Inkscape. I just tried it, and it seems to work when opening the SVG in Krita

Comment: Wow, it worked. Thank you very much! BTW, do you know why this happened?
PS: Do I need to close the topic? If so, how?

Comment: I've added an answer now plus a little more info. If you think it solves your problem, you can choose it as best answer.

Comment: Ok. Just a thing: as you said, now, I can see the text in the browser and in Krita, but not in Drive haha. Somehow... But I think it won't be a problem. At the end it will be printed in a shirt so... it will appear there, right?

Comment: When you have stuff printed, make sure you ask your printer for a proof before they proceed, or alternatively also send them a jpeg as a visual aid so they can check what it should look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the text to paths in Inkscape.  I just tried it and it seems to work.

I'm not entirely sure why, but perhaps Krita has some different way of rendering text point sizes in an SVG, since converting to paths removes all references to point sizes.  Note that converting text to paths is also an easy way to solve the problem of text disappearing when viewing an SVG in a browser.